# Why does my Image changes its brightness depending on the offset? (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a basic column with 10 LEDS and a custom cursor that is able to move up or down.  I already changed the zIndex to 1f so its always on top.

#### Why is my custom cursor changing its brightness if I change its offset position by dragging it up or down?

[image]

My goal is to achieve the same amount of brightness no matter where the cursor currently is.

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun Airflow(climateViewModel: ClimateViewModel = viewModel()) {

    var ypos by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)) {
        Box() {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .alpha(1f)
                    .zIndex(1f)
                    .offset(y = PixelToDp(pixelSize = ypos.toInt())),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.climate_slider_cursor),
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTapGestures(
                            onTap = {
                                ypos = it.y
                            },
                        )
                    }
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectVerticalDragGestures(
                            onDragStart = {
                                ypos = it.y
                            },
                            onVerticalDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                ypos = change.position.y
                            },
                            onDragEnd = {

                            },
                        )
                    }) {

                for (i in 9 downTo 0) {
                    Image(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),

                        painter = painterResource(id = climateViewModel.leds[i]),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.climate_slider_off),
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }


        }


        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = PixelToDp(pixelSize = 27))
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.climate_slider_fan),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your cursor drawable have 100% alpha?

Comment: Yes i explicitly set it to 1f (first Image after Box) even though I dont think it changed anything on the outcome

Comment: Not the drawable itself - either the fill colour (if it's a vector) or the pixel data. If the alpha isn't 100%, it can be affected by the colour/alpha it's being drawn over - if your LED drawables have varying alpha at different *y* positions, it would make the partially-transparent cursor look more or less visible (brighter or darker in this case) as it moves. Just something I'd look into, and whether it's happening consistently at certain positions. I don't know anything about Compose but drawing a drawable shouldn't be inconsistent like that, that's why I'd check the alpha interactions

Comment: I think it has todo with the resolution of my emulator vs my display resolution.It is 1536x2048 on 9.7inches for the emulator and 1920x1080 for my display. I tried it on another Display with higher resolution and it is almost not visible at (No change of brightness). I am still a bit confused and hope it will work on the real hardware without an emulator. Still thanks for your help @cactustictacs

Comment: Yeah it's possibly that it's just some kind of aliasing artifact, from trying to display a resolution that doesn't divide evenly into another. It's *probably* fine, especially if you've tested it on another emulator! One thing you could try is using your original emulator, move the thing so it looks wrong, and then try resizing the emulator window. If the appearance changes, that's a good sign you're right and it's just the resolution combo making it look weird on the emulator. And until you can test it on hardware devices, it's not a huge problem at least!